# how only some arguments to function C

Tags: c, function

I have this function:
`void func(int a, int b, char s, FILE *fp, int flag)`

and i want to use the function's args based on the flag. For example:

`func(num, NOTHING, NOTHING, file, 1)`
`func(num, othernum, NOTHING, NOTHING, 2)`
and on the function `this_is_function` i want to have:

```
void func(int a, int b, char s, FILE *fp, int flag){
if(flag == 1){
/* use a and file */
}
if(flag == 2){
/* use a,b */
}
/* etc etc */
}
```

i would like to know if it is possible and how to do this!
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You do not need to use all arguments passed into the function, so your code is fine.

Comment: Though this is not a C++ question, it might interest you that in C++ there is something called [boost::optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/examples.html#boost_optional.examples.optional_return_values) which provides this ability, and if you were using it then your "NOTHING" is a special value called `boost::none` (which you can easily equate to `none` if that doesn't conflict with other names in your project).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `0` to `int` and `char` and `NULL` for pointers when you call the function and the arguments are not used.

```
func(num, 0, 0, file, 1)
func(num, othernum, 0, NULL, 2)
```

You can also use variadic functions. Variadic functions are functions with a variable number of arguments.

Answer (score 4):

If by `NOTHING` you mean that you really want to omit that argument, I don't think it's possible the way you've outlined it.

The way this typically is done in C is through [variable argument lists](http://linux.die.net/man/3/stdarg). That would mean you'd have to reformulate so that the `flag` goes first, since it decides the rest of the arguments:

```
void func(int flag, ...)
{
  va_list args;
  int num, othernum;
  FILE *file;

  va_start(args, flag);
  if(flag == 1)
  {
    num = va_arg(args, int);
    file = va_arg(args, FILE *);
  }
  else if(flag == 2)
  {
    num = va_arg(args, int);
    othernum = va_args(args, int);
  }
  va_end(args);

  /* Inspect `flag` again, and do things with the values we got. */
}
```

Then you can use the function like so:

```
func(1, 42, a_file);
```

or

```
func(2, 17, 4711);
```

This of course requires lots of care, since you're not getting a lot of help from the compiler anymore to match the values provided in the call to what the function expects.

I would recommend restructuring it into different top-level functions instead, that call a common "worker" function with the proper arguments:

```
func_mode1(42, a_file);
func_mode2(17, 4711);
```

these could then call `func()` with the proper `flag` value, filling in suitable defaults for arguments that don't apply (such as `NULL` for a non-used file pointer).

Comment: oh thanks! This is interesting but i think it's more simple to use the thing described by Ouah :)

Answer (score 2):

Create seperate functions for each of the cases you are trying to handle. This would yield to more readable code. State your intention through your code rather than hack around it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work fine and moreover try it out once and check for any errors. I am sure as no error should occur. You can also try using `switch` case in the func with `flag` as the `choice` for `switch`. I am sure you are not going to use `Nothing` and `othersum` in your code.

Comment: yes, you're right :) they are only for example. However thanks for your answer :)